# Rewriting a hash request to get query string in next js

Tags: routes, next.js

I'm working on a project in next js.

I have route: `http://localhost:3000/loggedin` where the auth server sends a callback when user log in.

But I'm getting data like so with a hash:

```
#access_token=ba0...&id_token=eyJ...
```

Is there a way to redirect or rewrite this to get query string like so:

```
?access_token=ba0...&id_token=eyJ...
```

I have looked at redirects and rewrites in `next.config.js`

Any suggestions?

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/loggedin:params*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'query',
            key: 'access_token',
          },
        ],
        destination: '/loggedin?access_token=:access_token',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```